# Is there a branch of machine learning that can deal with near infinite state spaces

Tags: machine-learning, model, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

So I have a game type problem defined as follows;

```
Up to 10 players
Each player has:
64 tiles
200 piece types
Up to 20 pieces in play at any time
```

There's a random component on what pieces a player can get (equivalent to a dice roll - plus a choice of one of 4 or don't take any). Everything else is deterministic, you have a limited Heath and you just duke it out 1 v 1 (if there's more than 2 then your opponent is chosen randomly) losing a battle costs you some amount of HP, when it's gone you're out - last one standing wins.

I'm not great at working out the number of states (there's 64 tiles, but only a max 20 can be used at once) but in simple terms if each tile could contain any one of the 200 pieces then we have 64^200 right? That's a crazy big number, and from the perspective of training an AI, it's a large enough number that it might as well be infinity.

So is there a branch of machine learning that can handle this type of problem, where the state space is so huge that there's no way to look at every possibility? I was hoping to use something like Q learning, an algorithm that's independent of the problem - am I correct that this wont be possible for the described game.

Comment: wouldn't Go fall into this category of very large state spaces?

Comment: Why would a neural network using reinforcement learning (as used for Go, chess, Shogi, StarCraft, Dota2 etc.) not work here?

Comment: @Björn Maybe I'm wrong about it, but I was concerned that a reinforcement learning algorithm would miss a large section of the state space (the majority of it)... is that not an issue?

Comment: @user6916458 Deep Q-Learning is an option. In general you are looking for function approximation instead of tabular methods. It is true that only a tiny portion of the state space can be explored but it is also only a tiny portion of the state space that is relevant. Most states you'll never reach in a realistic game anyway.

Comment: I just answered a very similar question here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/49511/what-will-be-the-policy-if-the-state-space-is-continuous-in-reinforcement-learni